# ExportToPNG produces shifted images

Tags: arcpy, wms, data-driven-pages, png

I am using ExportToPNG (in ArcGIS 10.3.1) to produce images from a MXD with WMS data.
If I use the interface command `ExportMap` with the option `"1-BIT_MONOCHROME_THRESHOLD"` and a threshold at `256`, the image I get is perfect.
But if I put this in a python to produce a series of images through DataDrivenPage, the output images are empty.

Here is my code:

```
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
  mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
  arcpy.AddMessage(pageNum)
  df.scale=5000
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, cartella + os.sep + "F" + str(pageNum) +    ".png",df,world_file=True,color_mode="1-BIT_MONOCHROME_THRESHOLD",background_color=256)
```

Consider that I force `df.scale=5000` to ensure the WMS data are displayed, because a scale_limit of 6000 is defined for that layer.
I see the dataframe panning to all pages, the scale is 1:5000 and the WMS data are visible, all the PNG files are produced, but they are white!
I tried the same with a gridIndex, not using DataDrivenPage, but the result is exactly the same.

**UPDATE - 3 Dec 2019**

Some more trials on this problem. If I fix a scale 1:3000, finally I get an image with the desired features from the WMS! But the image is not correctly georeferenced: it is slightly shifted with an increasing shift from the center toward all borders.

I also tried `ExportToJPEG` instead of PNG: in this case the images are perfect, but not usable for the vectorization I want to do after. In fact, though the ESRI documentation indicates the same parameters for all formats (PNG, JPG, TIF etc) the 1-BIT option is only applicable with the PNG, as you can see working with the "ExportMap" interface.

So the problem now is modified: not "empty images" but "shifted images".

Comment: Try copying your layers to another mxd and retry DDP.

Comment: Made some more trials and added description. Now the problem is: not "empty images" but "shifted images"

Comment: Are the coordinate systems of the WMS and your map data frame the same? If not, try matching your df’s CS with the WMS.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are providing "df" to the *data_frame* parameter. When you provide this parameter you must also specify a data frame export width and height. Otherwise these values will default to 640 pixel width and 480 pixel height. It is possible this is why you are seeing a shift in your exported images.Compared to when you exported to PNG through the user interface.

I would suggest performing the export through the user interface like you did before and if it performs correctly then go to your [Results Window](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/using-the-results-window.htm). You can then drag the successful geoprocesing result into your python window and see the parameters that resulted in the correct PNG export. You can then use these parameters in your code.

Documentation for [arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopng.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I did find the solution on my own.
Despite the declaration of the WMS provider about the scale limit (stated at 1:6000) I have put my scale at 1:3000 and the procedure works. Of course it is much slower than expected ... but this is another problem.

The second problem I had (the shift in images) was due simply to the ArcMap version: it appeared because one test was performed on 10.1, and disappeared working on 10.3.1.

Anyway I think the `ExportToPNG` function suffer some problem: I still got errors if I try to call it using PAGE_LAYOUT instead of dataframe and an explicit parameter for the threshold to be used in case of `"1-BIT_MONOCHROME_THRESHOLD"` is not declared. Furthermore, if I try `ExportToJPEG`, the online documentation is exactly the same ad the PNG case, while the option `"1-BIT_MONOCHROME_THRESHOLD"` is not applicable ... and other minor amenities.

My final code is like this:

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(index,['FID','Shape@','PageName','PageNumber'] , whe):
      nf =  row[2]
      arcpy.AddMessage  ("foglio: " + nf)
      file_out = cartella + os.sep + nf + ".png"
      feat = row[1]
      extent = feat.extent
      df.extent = extent
      df.scale = 3000
      arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd,file_out,df,1570,899,96,True,"1-BIT_MONOCHROME_THRESHOLD",256)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes... for `1-BIT_MONOCHROME_THRESHOLD`, we need to assign the threshold value. There is no option for it in this function. So it is not working.

Comment: Could you please clarify if this is a question or an answer?